# How to configure a distributed hashtable on Kubernetes?

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My application is running in Kubernetes pods and I would like to use [golang/groupcache](https://github.com/golang/groupcache) to distribute key/value entities amongst instances of the app.

The groupcache library in each of my app instances is required to know the connection details (IP & port) of all the other app instances so it can distribute the key/value entities as it sees fit. How can I let groupcache know the connection details of the other running instances of my application? Would it be preferable/possible to use the Kubernetes [Go Client Library](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)?

Answer (score 2):

Go Client Library is one of the options. Another (more simple) option is to setup a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for groupcache, so with a single DNS lookup you can get all IP addresses of all groupcache pods.